# How to persist my class change with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```js
const changeNavbarButton = () => {


  const navbarBox = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-icon-box");

  navbarBox.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const navbarBoxActive = document.querySelector(".navbar-icon-box-active")
      navbarBoxActive.classList.remove("navbar-icon-box-active")
      event.currentTarget.classList.add("navbar-icon-box-active");
      console.log(event.currentTarget);
    });
  });
};

changeNavbarButton();
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #161616;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar-icon-box {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-icon-box p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-icon-box-active {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.navbar-icon-box-active p {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-icon-box navbar-icon-box-active">
    <p>Home</p>
  </a>

  <a class="navbar-icon-box">
    <p>Events</p>
  </a>

  <a class="navbar-icon-box">
    <p>Profile</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Hi everyone, I'm stuck with something I can't figure out. When I click on a navbar button, my console.log() displays this:
`<a class="navbar-icon-box navbar-icon-box-active" href="/"></a>`

It seems to work, however I can't see any change in my browser. When I inspect the navbar button I just clicked on, it just displays the first class `navbar-icon-box` without add the new one. What am I missing ?

Comment: Can't see any problem. Can you post a[example]?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new as developer and still didn't have the good practice... I added my HTML and CSS files, hope it will help to reproduce the environment

Comment: I made a Stack Snippet, but as you can see when you run it, it doesn't produce the problem you describe. Can you edit it so that running it results in the problem, so that it can be debugged?

Comment: Ok thank you, I changed a bit my code but I can't reproduce exactly the same bug I'm having on my localhost (nothing happens when I click on a button). However, the function I wrote doesn't seem work properly here with the snippet, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be occuring due to variable's life cycle.

I suggest you to use the codes down below where `navbarBoxActive` is not used over the addEventListeners.

```
const changeNavbarButton = () => {

  //const navbarBoxActive = document.querySelector(".navbar-icon-box-active")
  const navbarBox = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-icon-box");

  navbarBox.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      document.querySelector(".navbar-icon-box-active").classList.remove("navbar-icon-box-active")
      event.currentTarget.classList.add("navbar-icon-box-active");
      console.log(event.currentTarget);
    });
  });
};

changeNavbarButton();
```

or

```
const changeNavbarButton = () => {

  const navbarBox = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-icon-box");

  navbarBox.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const navbarBoxActive = document.querySelector(".navbar-icon-box-active");
      navbarBoxActive.classList.remove("navbar-icon-box-active")
      event.currentTarget.classList.add("navbar-icon-box-active");
      console.log(event.currentTarget);
    });
  });
};

changeNavbarButton();
```

Comment: It works with the snippet! Thank you :) I maybe figured out why it doesn't appear in my localhost: I think it's because of my tag link and its ```href```, I should put my class in the div, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Problem is pre-defined variable refers to wrong node while class referer is constantly changing.